# Underfull \hbox in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, warnings, urls

I am getting lots of "`Underfull \hbox`" warnings that point to the `*.bbl` file. It looks like these messages appear only when URLs are very long, like in the below example:

```
@techreport{nistguidesec,
  author    = {Wayne Jansen and Timothy Grance},
  title     = {Guidelines on Security and Privacy in Public Cloud Computing},
  month    = {January},
  note     = {Draft Special Publication 800-144. Available at \url{http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-144/Draft-SP-800-144_cloud-computing.pdf}},
}
```

In the produced PDF text is correctly hyphened and links are correctly split over several lines (I am using `hyperref` package)

How can I avoid annoying warning messages about "`underfull \hbox`" pointing to bibliography?

Comment: lockstep already gave a very nice answer, but one thing I've found sometimes works it to insert a `\\ ` before the `\url` Of course, this is a manual solution.

Comment: @TH. IMHO `\protect\linebreak` might be better than `\\ `, because it doesn't affect the justification.

Comment: @Skillmon Good point.

Comment: @Skillmon is it possible to have `\protect\linebreak` right before Available?

Comment: @alper can be put anywhere, but you might get underfull lines with this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Because "line-breaking in the bibliography is often more difficult than in the body text" (biblatex manual, p. 91), LaTeX typesets the bibliography using the `\sloppy` macro which relaxes some of TeX's parameters/penalties for line-breaking. However, `\sloppy` (maybe for some good reason!) does not touch `\hbadness` which is (among other things) responsible for "`Underfull \hbox`" warnings. The following code (to be added to your preamble) appends `\hbadness 10000` to `\sloppy` which should remove those warnings.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}
```

Alternatively (and without possible adverse affects), you could typeset the bibliography `\raggedright`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}
```

Minimal example (compilable):

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth 300pt

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Variant A
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}
% Variant B
% \apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{nistguidesec,
  author    = {Wayne Jansen and Timothy Grance},
  title     = {Guidelines on Security and Privacy in Public Cloud Computing},
  month    = {January},
  note     = {Draft Special Publication 800-144. Available at \url{http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-144/Draft-SP-800-144_cloud-computing.pdf}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: IMHO it should be `\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}`, just to be sure. Or use `\@M` for `10000` if `\makeatletter` is already in affect.

Comment: @Martin: I corrected my code samples to include `\relax`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have just put a space after the number. Since you mention `\raggedright`, it's probably worth mentioning that `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` is almost certainly a better choice.

Comment: Why is this preferred to say
`\begingroup
\hbadness 10000\relax
\printbibliography
\endgroup`? I tried `\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}` but it had no effect.

Comment: @AndrewBate one reason may be that it allows you to separate style from content, as you can amend `\sloppy` in the preamble. (Of course, you could also amend `\printbibliography` in the preamble.) Another reason may be that you may not want to change bibliographies that do not use `\sloppy`...

Comment: In my case, the bibliography is messed up by splitting the words apart trying to fill the whole line and accommodate for the long URL that follows, so `raggedright` is the solution. ```latex
\begin{raggedright}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{raggedright}
```