# How to fill an underfull box in footnote with url?

Tags: footnotes, warnings, urls

Could someone help to correct the warning I get related to an underfull box with the following code? I have tried `\hfill`, `hspace*{\hfill}` etc with no luck.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,draft]{svjour3}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url} 

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref} %make hyperlinks references
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links
        citecolor=blue,linktocpage=true}
\usepackage{breakurl}


\begin{document}

\title{Something}

Microsoft continued to gain market \footnote{\url{www.some-asd-sdsasdasd-asdas-dasdas-dasdas-asd.com}}

\end{document}
```

So the answer to this is to use: the following:
    `\usepackage{ragged2e}

    \footnote{\RaggedRight\url{www.some-asd-sdsasdasd-asdas-dasdas-dasdas-asd.com}}`

Credits to [How can I make my text never go over the right margin by always hyphenating or breaking on word-boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-make-my-text-never-go-over-the-right-margin-by-always-hyphenating-or-b/9110#9110)

Comment: Man I gave up trying to fix those types of error/s a long time ago...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Things like that require luck; it's nearly impossible to break correctly paragraphs with long URLs. Can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: Nope :). IMO this example expresses all I want. I have a long url in a footnote which breaks into multiple rows (in a two column class) and does not fill the box.

Comment: while it's possible to break a url, i think it may not be possible to get rid of the underfull box message.  i worked on a project a long time ago that needed to break long words (not just urls) automatically.  we got the breaks we needed (with proper hyphenation), but just learned to live with the underfull box messages.  there were few enough that they could easily be checked.

Answer (score 8):

As already stated, the command `\raggedright` should do the trick, whether you are using `\url` or another command.

No package is needed for this, as it is already a built in LaTeX command.

```
Microsoft continued to gain market \footnote{\raggedright\url{www.some-asd-sdsasdasd-asdas-dasdas-dasdas-asd.com}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the following code snippet from another question:

```
\newcommand{\url}[1]{%
\begingroup
\ttfamily
 \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
 \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
 \catcode`/=\active\catcode`.=\active
 \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
 \endgroup
}
```

Comment: I commented \usepackage{url} and it doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an `\hfill` before the `\url`, i.e. `\footnote{\hfill\url{...}}`, removes the warning. The only drawback of this is that it pushes the first part of the URL to the right, so that you have some extra space between the footnote number and the URL.

Another idea ist to use `\footnote{\rlap{\url{...}}}`. This printes the URL but ignores its width completely. The URL will stick out to the second column then, though, if it is too long.

Comment: Yeap. So IMO none of these are really useful!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
\footnote{\sloppy\url{www.some-asd-sdsasdasd-asdas-dasdas-dasdas-asd.com}}
```

Comment: I am sorry this does not work.

Comment: it works for me ...

Comment: Do you use  \usepackage{lmodern}? because if I comment this,then yes it works...but then I have other warnings like:LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <4.25> not available

Comment: I run `pdflatex` without loading package `breakurl` which makes no sense

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to work for me.  The only thing it works is to add the following code: `\usepackage{etoolbox}  
\apptocmd{\sloppy}    {\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}` taken from [1] with `\sloppy`.  But should I do this in a journal. I do not think that this is acceptable....  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/underfull-hbox-in-bibliography?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `\href{<my_url>}{<description>}` command. You can add the`url` as `description` so that the text can be broken up correctly. Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Data clustered into three groups \footnote{Source:\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster\_analysis\#/media/File:KMeans-Gaussian-data.svg}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster\_analysis\#/media/File:KMeans-Gaussian-data.svg}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Applying \href{}{} to a long url]