# How to fill horizontal space properly in underfull multilined url (in footnote)?

Tags: footnotes, urls, letterspacing

**Footnote code:**

```
\footnote{\url{http://blog.draw.io/creating-custom-stylizable-shapes-with-specific-connection-points} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}.
```

The footnote produces a multiline output (2 lines) due to being so long.

**LaTeX-complaint:**

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines [footnote]
```

**Rendered output:**

[image: Underfull \hbox]

**My approach based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88558/80532) answer:**

```
\footnote{\hfill\url{http://blog.draw.io/creating-custom-stylizable-shapes-with-specific-connection-points} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}.
```

It removes the complaint but produces this ugly output:

[image: Indentation]

**Question:**

How can I apply changes to my code to get a URL that starts at the outmost left and fills the `\hbox` completely?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[
        final,
        numbers=noenddot,
        a4paper, 
        12pt, 
        oneside
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
        a4paper, 
        top=2.0cm, 
        left=2.0cm, 
        right=4.0cm, 
        bottom=2.0cm, 
        includehead, 
        includefoot
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\linespread{1.2}
\footnotesep\baselineskip

\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear,
        isbn=false,
        doi=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{EndfassungLiteraturDatenbank.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
        \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

\usepackage{upquote}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}

\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{dirtree}

\emergencystretch=1em

\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}

Das Tool draw.io von JGraph hat den größten Funktionsumfang von allen getesteten Browser-basierten Tools. Mit ihm kann man u.a. UML, ERD, Flowcharts, BPMN und sogar Android- und iOS-User-Interfaces erstellen. Die technologische Basis ist HTML5, CSS3 und JavaScript. 
Canvas wird nicht verwendet, stattdessen werden <div>-Tags benutzt, worin die SVG-Shapes (ein Shape ist ein Notationselement) angezeigt werden. Die Begründung der Entwickler ist, dass Canvas vom Internet Explorer bis Version 8 nicht unterstützt wird. Das JavaScript besteht aus den Open Source libraries "`MathJax.js"' und "`jscolor.js"', der sonstige JavaScript-Code ist proprietär (53.700 Zeilen entminifizierte app.js zuzüglich kleinerer Helfer-Skripte). Für das Anlegen von Shapes wird ein XML-Editor bereitgestellt. 
JGraph hat dazu eine eigene Sprache entwickelt: XML Stencil Language\footnote{\url{http://blog.draw.io/draw-dot-io-mxgraph-xml-stencil-format} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{\url{http://blog.draw.io/creating-custom-stylizable-shapes-with-specific-connection-points} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}. 

\end{document}
```

**Update 1:**

After [this answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255053/80532) my problem with the margin to the footnote number has been solved. However, the underfull `\hbox` remains like also visible in this screenshot:

[image: Still underfull hbox]

Comment: Can you add a minimal compilable example?

Comment: I obliged, sire `:)`

Comment: You get the same result with a long textual footnote.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `scrartcl` does by default:

> The default configuration of the KOMA-Script classes is:
>
> ```
> \deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}
>   {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
> ```

(section 3.14 of the manual)

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
        final,
        numbers=noenddot,
        a4paper, 
        12pt, 
        oneside
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{url}

\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

% change the default spacing in footnotes
\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{8}

Das Tool draw.io von JGraph hat den größten Funktionsumfang von allen getesteten Browser-basierten Tools. Mit ihm kann man u.a. UML, ERD, Flowcharts, BPMN und sogar Android- und iOS-User-Interfaces erstellen. Die technologische Basis ist HTML5, CSS3 und JavaScript. 
Canvas wird nicht verwendet, stattdessen werden <div>-Tags benutzt, worin die SVG-Shapes (ein Shape ist ein Notationselement) angezeigt werden. Die Begründung der Entwickler ist, dass Canvas vom Internet Explorer bis Version 8 nicht unterstützt wird. Das JavaScript besteht aus den Open Source libraries "`MathJax.js"' und "`jscolor.js"', der sonstige JavaScript-Code ist proprietär (53.700 Zeilen entminifizierte app.js zuzüglich kleinerer Helfer-Skripte). Für das Anlegen von Shapes wird ein XML-Editor bereitgestellt. 
JGraph hat dazu eine eigene Sprache entwickelt: XML Stencil Language\footnote{\url{http://blog.draw.io/draw-dot-io-mxgraph-xml-stencil-format} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{\url{http://blog.draw.io/creating-custom-stylizable-shapes-with-specific-connection-points} (besucht am 16.06.2015)}. 

x\footnote{Some long footnote that runs across two lines; just
make the text long enough and add some words to be sure.

Let's also have a paragraph break in the footnote so that also
the second mandatory argument to \texttt{\string\deffoonote} shows
its effect.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the `\deffoonote` line, I get

[image]

Note that the indent is not caused by the URL, but is also present in textual footnotes.

Comment: Wow, OK, that solves one part of the problem, the margin to the footnote number. But Latex still complains about an underfull `\hbox`. I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @Karl There's no possibility of filling that space.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to get a clean LaTeX-result? The problem causes the last bad box in my entire thesis and the last error/warning at all `:-/`

Comment: @Karl Either `points` can be placed in the line or there's no way for filling it. I don't think that adding space around hyphens or letter spacing is acceptable. My opinion is that URLs should simply be given a key and listed in an appendix.

Comment: @Karl -- If you really must use a fixed-width font, you are limiting ways to make it fit. One (rather unsatisfactory) option might be to reduce the size of just that URL. Only people really looking for imperfections are likely to notice the difference, and they might well be the same people who would be able to intuit the reason for the difference.

Comment: I let the matter rest and go with egregs code. As he is into TeX since 1987 his words reassured me to hand in the thesis with that "flaw" `:)`