# How to "really" solve the problem of "underfull \hbox" when typesetting url in footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

I ran across the problem of underfull \hbox when I want to typeset a long url(long enough to fill two lines) in the footnote. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

We use this dataset
\footnote{\url{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}}
for experimentation.
\end{document}
```

After searching the web, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88553/how-to-fill-an-underfull-box-in-footnote-with-url) suggests using `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package.
But I think the `\RaggedRight`does not "really" solve this problem, it just hides the "underfull \hbox" warning. 
Below is the produced footnote of the above MWE:
[image]

After using the `\RaggedRight` command, i.e., change from

```
\footnote{\url{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}}
```

in the MWE to

```
\footnote{\RaggedRight\url{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}}
```

. The warning disappears. But the produced footnote is (in my opinion) the same as before, see the image below:
[image]

My question is, how to "really" solve this problem? In my naive thought, why not LaTeX move some charcters from the second line, say the characters "+Multipl", to the empty space in the end of first line. After all, url are just a series of
charcters, why not stuff the first line with some charcters from the second line to make full use of first line?
Or there are some hidden facts which are very complicated?

Any answers or pointer to answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than breaking mid-word, you can re-introduce some stretch space around the break characters (`.` and `/` here) I use

```
\Urlmuskip=0mu  plus 10mu
```

which allows more than enough flexibility in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\Urlmuskip=0mu  plus 10mu
\begin{document}

We use this dataset
\footnote{\url{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}}
for experimentation.

\vfill

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\url` tries hard to break the url only at "sensible" places. But if you don't like this you can allow \url to break everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{%
\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f%
\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m%
\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z%
\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G%
\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U%
\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

We use this dataset
\footnote{\url{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with++Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}}
for experimentation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that as there are no stretchable spaces the line is still a bit underfull.

Comment: might not microtype help by slightly deforming the characters in the string?  (not saying that it's a good idea ...)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, why are there still underfull warning when the first line is seemingly fully used?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Perhaps, but not by default (microtype imho doesn't expand typewriter fonts, beside this url uses math spacing).

Comment: @ the code in the preamble is a bit long (no offence), is there a more elegant way to do that? By the way, any pointer to how the calculation of badness works(the badness is still 10000, not changed)

Comment: You can active font expansion for the typewriter if you want to get rid of the underfull hbox: `\usepackage{microtype}\UseMicrotypeSet [expansion] {alltext}`.

Comment: @Hao -- Length and elegance in code do not necessarily have a one-to-one correspondence. `hyperref.sty` itself is nearly 9000 lines long. But there's nothing to prevent you from putting the code inbetween the `\makeat...`commands into your own `.sty` file that you load after `hyperref`....

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `\usepackage{microtype}\UseMicrotypeSet [expansion] {alltext}` does not solve the problem. There are still "underfull \hbox" warning.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to replace `\url` with `\href`. However, if your URL does not contain any breakable character (e.g. `-`), you will have to help it find by inserting some `\hspace{0pt}` (zero-width space) at strategic locations.

In your case, I added one after each '+'.

```
\footnote{\href{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+Speech+Dataset+with+Multiple+Types+of+Sound+Recordings\#}{http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinson+\hspace{0pt}Speech+\hspace{0pt}Dataset+\hspace{0pt}with+\hspace{0pt}Multiple+\hspace{0pt}Types+\hspace{0pt}of+\hspace{0pt}Sound+\hspace{0pt}Recordings\#}}
```

Comment: The url can not be split into two lines if it is too long to fit in one line. Have you checked your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback. As mentioned above, I indeed checked it and it worked well on my own case. However I did notice that my URL happened to contains breakable chars (`-`) and that it would not work if an URL does not. In this case, one will have to insert some `\hspace{0pt}` at strategic locations in the text part. I updated my answer.

Comment: I think it is a bit awkward to manually adjust the url. If we have several url to process, it would be tedious and error-prone.

Comment: If I may, we’re talking about word processing not programming. This is latex not C or python :)